# When reverting to git previous commit how to cherry pick?

Tags: git, git-revert

I have reverted the previous commit, with below command:
git reset HEAD~1 
then,
git stash to revert my last commit.

What I want to know, Is there any way to revert one by one, rather than using the stash ?

Comment: What's your end goal? Do you want to undo changes without breaking history (i.e. making new commits that are the reverse of old commits), do you want to undo changes without caring about history (i.e. just throwing away a set of commits from the branch), or do you want to just go back in time (i.e. not worrying about commits and look/modify code from a previous time)?

Comment: my goal is to split the last commit and undo/stash specific files only.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to loose the last commit without keeping it anywhere, you can do a hard reset.

```
git reset HEAD~1 --hard
```

This will remove the last commit and will not store that commit's changes anywhere else.

Comment: HEAD moved to last commit, but, it didn't uncommit my last version, can you please elaborate steps to uncommit step-by-step.

Comment: what do yo mean by it did not uncommit your last version?